# Settings icon missing on login screen 20.04

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, icons

I installed KDE (kde-full first then kbuntu-desktop) and the gear icon at the bottom right of the login screen is not showing to switch desktop environments.

I did try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Selected the one I wanted, 2:

[image: Screenshot]

Logged out and back in, still in Unity.

Can the missing Icon be added or do I need to remove KDE and re-isntall kbuntu-desktop only? Or, can I add the missing icon somehow? I'd like to not have to fully install Kbuntu from a boot drive and re-install all my apps.

Answer (score 1):

As an IT service desk manager, I should have known. I fully rebooted. Issue resolved.